# converting xml into a pdf document?

Tags: asp.net, xml, xml-serialization, pdf-generation

I have a grid view i have exported all the details from the datatable into a xml document

Now i need to convert that xml document into a pdf document.
Can anyone tell how to convert the xml document into a pdf file in C#?

Answer (score 0):

Might need to expand on your problem a bit!

But generally you'd first need a template with a place/coordinate for each element. Not sure about c# but we use indesign templates which along with a custom adobe air app imports xml data into the template, saves a version and then exports it to several pdfs for print and web.

Answer (score 0):

you will need a library that can generate PDF's. Most reporting libraries have this feature builtin, usually an export or print option.

as @danielCrabbe stated. a report consists of data and a template. data is loaded into the template and exported as a PDF.

Answer (score 0):

First, you will need to create a [XSL-FO](http://w3schools.sinsixx.com/xslfo/default.asp.htm) transformation file. Have a look at these [examples](https://www.antennahouse.com/antenna1/xml-to-xsl-fo-stylesheets/).

Then, you can use [FoNET](https://fonet.codeplex.com/) as a XSL-FO to PDF renderer.

```
public static bool XMLToPDF(string pXmlFile, string pXslFile, string pFoFile, string pPdfFile)
{
    string lBaseDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(pXslFile);
    XslCompiledTransform lXslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
    lXslt.Load(pXslFile);
    lXslt.Transform(pXmlFile, pFoFile);
    FileStream lFileInputStreamFo = new FileStream(pFoFile, FileMode.Open);
    FileStream lFileOutputStreamPDF = new FileStream(pPdfFile, FileMode.Create);
    FonetDriver lDriver = FonetDriver.Make();
    lDriver.BaseDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(lBaseDir);
    lDriver.CloseOnExit = true;
    lDriver.Render(lFileInputStreamFo, lFileOutputStreamPDF);
    lFileInputStreamFo.Close();
    lFileOutputStreamPDF.Close();
    return System.IO.File.Exists(pPdfFile);
}
```